# ASP.Net MVC's OAuthWebSecurity for Google

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, google-plus, google-oauth

Does ASP.Net MVC's OAuthWebSecurity for Google use Google's OAuth 2.0 for authentication?  ASP.Net MVC's OAuthWebSecurity for Google does not have ability to enter key or secret like Facebook and Twitter clients.  Likewise, no token is returned from a successful Google authentication.  Why is Google client different from Facebook and Twitter clients?

Is ASP.Net MVC's OAuthWebSecurity for Google using Google Plus, or some other approach for Google authentication?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're still looking for an implementation, please [try mine](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2) - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reflected over the OAuthWebSecurity class and it is using Google OpenID interface for authentication. It's not doing OAuth.  Currently, i think you will have to bake your own DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.IAuthentication implementation. I am actually embarking on the same adventure.